# Python Pandas: Month value changes into day after conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains the date column. It looks like as follow:
[image]

I tried to convert the object type of 'Retrieval date' column in proper datetime and set the format into 'd/m/Y' using following statement:

```
big_frame['Retrieval date'] = pd.to_datetime(big_frame['Retrieval date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

After running the above command, I noticed that it changes a few months value into day as shown in the following example:

[image]

The dates underlined with red color changes its month value into the day. I am not sure where I made the mistake. Could anyone help me where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your `to_datetime()` is converting the values to M/D/YYYY

Try this:

```py
pd.to_datetime(big_frame['Retrieval date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```